# split JSON object according the total number and odd/even number

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

The goal I'd like to achieve is that, count total number of JSon object first `console.log(Jobj.length);` for example, I now got 13 items.

Inside of `#red` div should be 7 items inside, `Math.round(Jobj.length/2)`, Inside of `#blue` div should be 6 `Math.floor(Jobj.length/2)`, if I have 14 items, then `#red` and `#blue` all have 7 items.

Now the question is that, how do I split the way I want, to split the first 7 to #red, rest to #blue.
I have done partically, if someone could help?

http://jsfiddle.net/6LmFL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now. I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6LmFL/2/.

This is the part I modified:

```
$.each(Jobj, function(i,v){
 if(i<7) {
  ($('<p>').text(v.item)).appendTo('.col1');
 }
 else {
   ($('<p>').text(v.item)).appendTo('.col2');
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I should have tried if statement then ask :-) thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the array `slice()` method to get a subsequence of the array:

```
var redcount = Math.ceil(Jobj.length/2); // Use Math.ceil() to put the excess in #red
var red = Jobj.slice(0, redcount);
var blue = JObj.slice(redcount);
```

Then you can display the contents of `red` and `blue` however you wish in the DIVs.

Answer (score 1):

More precise answer

```
var half = Math.floor( Jobj.length / 2);
for (var i=0;i<Jobj.length ;i++) {
    if (i<=half) {
         ($('<p>').text(Jobj[i].item)).appendTo('.col1');
    } else {
        ($('<p>').text(Jobj[i].item)).appendTo('.col2');
    }
}
```

Edit : look at Barmar's solution. It's waaay proper ! BUT it demands more lines of code :)